# New android studio rendering issue with 'coordinatorLayoutStyle'

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, sdk, android-constraintlayout, android-virtual-device

I had android studio and it was perfect without any problem. Everything was going right until I reinstall my windows to make PC a little faster. And then I install android studio the latest one. And though the last one was also up to date, there were no problem at all. But, in the new android studio any project I start or any project I open which has constraintLaoyout, the design view of xml get stuck with following errors.

> Rendering Problem
>
> Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme

Second error when I put any widget or anything on my activity

> Missing Constraints in ConstraintLayout
>
> This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it
> will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints  The
> layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and
> it records the current position with designtime attributes (such as
> layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime,
> so if you push your layout on a device, the widgets may appear in a
> different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a
> widget has both horizontal and vertical constraints by dragging from
> the edge connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. Writing this answer so that other can get help form similar kind of problem.

By default when we create a new project in android studio, it uses the latest API from SDK. In my case it was API 28. But, API 28 was incomplete or partially installed. I tried installing the API 28 completely but it did not work for some reason. Then I deleted that API 28 and installed API 27 latest. And by doing this when I create or open any new project that uses the API 27 and gets all the required things in there. And that is how I solved my problem.

Thanks everyone guys who tried to help me.

Answer (score 1):

First, update your project to use the latest build version. This helps fix a lot of problems when it comes to most Android views.

Second, go to your style and add this line of code to fix the first error

```
<item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
```

Third, the children of `CoordinaterLayout` must be constrained, if you are new to this layout, you can switch to `RelativeLayout` or you can use the design view to add constraints. View the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout)

A helpful video on constraints [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5o2hGMMmIw)

Answer (score 1):

I found the implementations of dependencies in `build.graddle(Module: app)` were API 28 but there was only API 26 in following directory

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7
```

So I deleted all SDK platforms and build tools and installed them with API 26 in SDK manager(select `Show Package Details`).
Then I started new project. The projects made with API 26 had no rendering problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding design library in your build.gradle?
If not then just add it
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

Comment: Yes, I tried. It now currently running with 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3' . But no result at all.